# ffmpeg since update to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg

Ever since I updated to 14.04 (from 13.10), each time I launch the Software Updater, it shows on the list of updates "ffmpeg derived postprocessing library". Yet, it also says on the same window about the ffmpeg update: 'The update has already been downloaded'!!?. When I then click on Install Now, it says about the ffmpeg update: 'Package operation failed. The installation or removal of a software package failed.' I can't say I've a clue what to do with this update.

How do I stop it being listed on the list of updates each time I fire the Software Updater?

More importantly, do I need to have that update? Have to say, the computer as such seems to be working all right. Can't say I've noticed anything...so far any way :)

Would be grateful for any answers to any of the Qs above.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I stop it being listed on the list of updates each time I fire the Software Updater?

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>
```

If the computer seems to be working properly then you are free to hold that package.

Comment: OP should choose this answer as it is the only correct answer. The other answers are all discussing how to add or setup ffmpeg, whereas the OP has clearly asked "how to stop the package from getting listed in updates".

Comment: FYI, It is still listed after I run your command: `sudo apt-mark hold libpostproc52`, it just isn't ticked. It would be great to get rid of this library but it seems to still be in use by other packages.

Answer (score 1):

14.04 does not offer anything from FFmpeg. Originally, the actual `ffmpeg` and libraries from FFmpeg were provided, but then Ubuntu switched to a fork that offered a counterfeit "`ffmpeg`". The fork eventually dropped their false "`ffmpeg`", and Ubuntu did the same at 14.04.

If you want the real `ffmpeg`, then either get a static build from the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page, or follow a [guide to compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo apt-mark hold libpostproc52
```

Now your software updates will proceed smoothly, even though the library is still shown in update manager, just in an un-ticked state.

Solutions that totally remove the package or remove it from the software updater package list completely are welcome.